# any way to tackle float Counter values in python

Tags: python

I was writing a program for averaging some values. Details: I was having a folder and within which I got many `.txt` files with `float` numbers.
All I was doing is summing up the float values and storing them in a `Counter` for each files.
After that I want to add up all values in the `Counter` and divide them by total no. of files(i.e.`.txt`).

But up to storing in a `Counter` goes fine, but when I want add up the values present in the `Counter` by using `sum(Counter.values())` then it raises an error showing `'float' object has no attribute 'values'`
I have gone through the manuals also, they are also saying it is possible for integer values.
But is there any was to add up `float` values within a counter.

Comment: Can you provide some code? Why are you using a `Counter` if all you want is the totals?

Comment: It doesn't sound like you're using [`collections.Counter`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), so you should clarify what `Counter` is in your question. BTW, if you're on Python2 (instead of Python3), Raymond Hettinger has a pretty awesome [backport recipe](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576611/).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why are you using a [`Counter` object](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) for summing values in files?  Its stated purpose is "for counting hashable objects" (i.e. if you have multiple *discrete* objects that you want to count instances of).

If you want to store a sum floating point values from each file, try a regular dictionary:

```
floatsums = {}
floatsums['file1.txt'] = ... // insert code to sum the floats

total = sum(floatsums.values())
numfiles = len(floatsums)
```

Answer (score 6):

Despite what the documentation says, it works perfectly well to put float values into a `Counter`. Try it yourself.

```
    from collections import Counter

    a = Counter()
    a['a'] += 1
    a['a'] += 0.1
    a['b'] += 0.1
    print(list(a.items()))
```

In Python 3, at least. This gives

```
    [('a', 1.1), ('b', 0.1)]
```

This works in both Python 2 and 3. Of course, since this isn't what the documentation says, it's technically undefined behavior, so it may not work in future versions, but I doubt it. Still, if you want to be completely specs-compliant, you can do this:

```
    from collections import defaultdict

    a = defaultdict(float)
```

This will give you the same result as above and only uses documented features.

Comment: +1 for the defaultdict solution, but -1 for the undocumented one. To use an undocumented feature is probably not a good idea.

Comment: Typing is going to support non-int values in `Counter`: https://github.com/python/typeshed/issues/3438

Answer (score 4):

Even simpler:

```
from collections import defaultdict
sums = defaultdict(lambda: 0)
```

then:

```
sums['a'] += 1.
```

Comment: Or even better, `sums = defaultdict(int)`, but this is not a good answer. A `Collection` does the same thing as this but more efficiently and with a better API.